# redis-cli redirected to 127.0.0.1

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-cli

I started Redis cluster on PC1, then connected it on PC2. When needed to redirect to another cluster node, it shows `Redirected to slot [7785] located at 127.0.0.1`, but should show `Redirected to slot [7785] located at [IP of PC1, like 192.168.1.20]`, then it shows an error. What is happening? What can I do?

The output:

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ redis-cli -c -h 192.168.1.20 -p 30001
192.168.1.20:30001> get foo
-> Redirected to slot [12182] located at 127.0.0.1:30003
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:30003: Connection refused
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:30003: Connection refused
not connected>
```

Output of `redis-cli -h 192.168.1.20 -p 30001 cluster nodes`:

```
5f6d6f1319318233917aba92b6ab0e244b3260d7 127.0.0.1:30004 slave 4c7b046ecaeb2dc689cbad21ee3466fb43b48fb9 0 14639
84410573 4 connected
e04d5b461cb6a2b48cb2a607e2140b7c1d32af25 127.0.0.1:30006 slave 3fc25c3851f7a9afd09b60739434118c25cd9243 0 14639
84410473 6 connected
3fc25c3851f7a9afd09b60739434118c25cd9243 127.0.0.1:30003 master - 0 1463984410573 3 connected 10923-16383
4c7b046ecaeb2dc689cbad21ee3466fb43b48fb9 127.0.0.1:30001 myself,master - 0 0 1 connected 0-5460
7383830ac84f199db346da3112b5aaf9e124d3cf 127.0.0.1:30005 slave 1eeeb51522aed364fcf9623d6045fa3df2748579 0 14639
84410573 5 connected
1eeeb51522aed364fcf9623d6045fa3df2748579 127.0.0.1:30002 master - 0 1463984410473 2 connected 5461-10922
```

Comment: What's the output of a `redis-cli -h 192.168.1.20 -p 30001 cluster nodes`?

Comment: @neuront Let me see it tomorrow on my work computer, thanks for your attention!

Comment: @neuront Hey man, I added the output of your needs in question description.Seems no problem about the cluster nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Hey could you try binding your redis cluster instance to server's IP

Update your redis.conf to add

> bind 172.31.28.76

PS- Update IP as required

Comment: @RobinChen if you are satisfied with the answer. kindly accept it to help the community

Answer (score 2):

That is because all your Redis IP addresses have updated to 127.0.0.1, and they believe other Redis are located in 127.0.0.1 too. That's not wrong if nodes in a cluster just communicate with each other, but definitely improper when a connection from other host want to know about the cluster.

In that situation, your client asked a Redis for a key it's not in charge and the Redis told the client to redirect to 127.0.0.1:30003. The client misunderstood it and tried to connect the port 30003 in its localhost, and certainly found nothing.

To fix it, try to send `cluster meet` with the right IP to each Redis in the cluster. I've made an experiment like this

```
# initial, Redis doesn't know its IP before a meet
127.0.0.1:7000> cluster nodes
8af9e47cb96f3bd8fff3800c38da11601157605d :7000 myself,master - 0 0 0 connected

# meet from 127.0.0.1, and their IP addresses updated to 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1:7000> cluster meet 127.0.0.1 7001
OK
127.0.0.1:7000> cluster nodes
8af9e47cb96f3bd8fff3800c38da11601157605d 127.0.0.1:7000 myself,master - 0 0 0 connected
2c3d9b6c29f21ecd846f42bcfb238099d88b57df 127.0.0.1:7001 master - 0 1463987186714 1 connected

# send another meet, use the eth0 IP other than lo
127.0.0.1:7000> cluster meet 172.31.28.76 7001
OK
127.0.0.1:7000> cluster nodes
8af9e47cb96f3bd8fff3800c38da11601157605d 127.0.0.1:7000 myself,master - 0 0 0 connected
2c3d9b6c29f21ecd846f42bcfb238099d88b57df 172.31.28.76:7001 master - 0 1463987192672 1 connected

# connect to :7001, its cluster nodes are what we expect
127.0.0.1:7001> cluster nodes
2c3d9b6c29f21ecd846f42bcfb238099d88b57df 172.31.28.76:7001 myself,master - 0 0 1 connected
8af9e47cb96f3bd8fff3800c38da11601157605d 172.31.28.76:7000 master - 0 1463987203631 0 connected
# send another meet to fix
127.0.0.1:7001> cluster meet 172.31.28.76 7000
OK

# back to :7000, its address updated
127.0.0.1:7000> cluster nodes
8af9e47cb96f3bd8fff3800c38da11601157605d 172.31.28.76:7000 myself,master - 0 0 0 connected
2c3d9b6c29f21ecd846f42bcfb238099d88b57df 172.31.28.76:7001 master - 0 1463987210539 1 connected
```

In your case you may send multiple `cluster meet` commands to each Redis to ensure its IP updated at all its peers.

Comment: I think so. But in product server, how can I do this? It should has configure to set, is't it?

Comment: I use the official "redis-trib.rb" file to create the cluster, maybe it's the reason? The command is :`redis-trib.rb create --replicas 1 127.0.0.1:30001 127.0.0.1:30002 127.0.0.1:30003 127.0.0.1:30004 127.0.0.1:30005 127.0.0.1:30006`, is here should be "192.168.1.20" not be "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: @RobinChen No, the nodes list is a dynamic config stored in the file specified by `cluster-config-file`. But you don't have to edit it manually or restart any of the redis-servers. Sending `cluster meet` commands via redis-cli will do.

Comment: @RobinChen That would surely cause the problem. You are supposed to use `192.168.1.20` (the eth0 address) in the first place.

Comment: And then, I use StackExchange.Redis in .Net project, how can I do? It's no way

Comment: I ever did this, but the three slave nodes seems cannot start.Let me try it again, thank you for your patient!

Comment: Hey man, I tried to change to "192.168.1.20". It's not work,it makes me a little crazy. It's also meet 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @RobinChen Could you give more details in an "update" section in your question? Including what you have done, and the recent logs output by each Redis. A log like "IP address for this node updated to" would appear if the address is updated.

Comment: Hey bro, I fixed it. That's the cache makes error. I clean the cluster config files use command "redisCluster clean" and start and create, it's work. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Hey bro, let's become friends? I like you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You said, you are running redis server on PC1. 
Then mention PC1's IP address (in your case it's `192.168.1.20`) while mentioning bind option in redis node config files.

Example of node config file for a cluster -

```
bind 192.168.1.20  
port 6000  
cluster-enabled yes  
cluster-config-file "nodes.conf"  
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `-c` option
for example you want to use client on port `6379`

`$ service redis-server start`

`$ redis-cli -c -p 6379`